# Handling Large stream with Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, pdf-generation, imagemagick-convert, pdfkit

Here is my attempt to convert an svg string to a png buffer using node and the imagemagick  convert tool. The png buffer is then used to draw an image in a pdf using pdfkit.

**Td;lr** I have a large svg string that needs to get to a child process "whole" (i.e not chunked). How do I do so?

This is an example that works for small files.

```
var child_process = require('child_process');
var pdfDocument = require('pdfkit');


var convert = child_process.spawn("convert", ["svg:", "png:-"]),
svgsrc =  '<svg><rect height="100" width="100" style="fill:red;"/></svg>';

convert.stdout.on('data', function(data) {  
    console.log(data.toString('base64')
    doc = new pdfDocument()
    doc.image(data)
}


convert.stdin.write(svgsrc);
convert.stdin.end()
```

This works when the svg string is 'small' (like the on provided in the example) -- I'm not sure where the cut-off from small to large is.

However, when attempting to use a larger svg string (something you might generate using D3) like this [ [large string](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/ParseThis/794c7a7fda24282a24e68835334aa681/raw/f9b1144cc0a09bcd22d84a6f85e765eec1e94811/large_svg.svg) ]. I run into:

> Error: Incomplete or corrupt PNG file

**So my question is: How do I ensure that the `convert`  child process reads the *entire* stream before processing it?**

A few things are known:

- The png buffer is indeed **incomplete**. I used a diff tool to check 
  the base64 string generated by the app
  versus the base64 of a png-to-svg converter online. The non-corrupted
  string is much larger than the corrupted string. (sorry I haven't
  been more specific with file size). That is, the convert tool seems
  to not be reading the entire source at any given time.
- The **source svg string is not corrupted** (as evidenced by the fact the the
  gist rendered it)
- When used in the command line the convert tool correctly generate a
  png file from a svg "stream" with `cat large_svg.svg | convert svg:png:-` So this is **not an issue with the convert tool**.

This lead me to down a rabbit hole of looking a node's buffer size for writeable and readable streams but to no avail. Maybe someone has worked with larger streams in node and can help out with getting the to work.

Comment: You have to buffer output **until the process ends.** *Never* assume the size of *chunks* passed to `'data'` event handlers. It could be 1 byte or it could be 1 megabyte.

Comment: Thanks! that worked, I just had to look into how to concat buffers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @mscdex pointed out I had to wait for the process to finish before 
attemping downstream work. All that was need was to wait for the `end` event on the `convert.stdout` stream and concatenate buffers on the `data` events.

```
// allocate a buffer of size 0
graph = Buffer.alloc(0)

// on data concat the incoming and the `graph`

convert.stdout.on('data', function(data) {

    graph = Buffer.concat([graph, data])
}
convert.stdout.on('end', function(signal) {

    // ... draw on pdf

}
```

**EDIT:**

Here is an more efficient version of the above where we use @mscdex 
suggestion to do the concatenation on the `end` callback and keeping a `chunksize` argument to help the Buffer allocate size when concatenation the chunks.

```
// allocate a buffer of size 0
var graph = [];
var totalchunks = 0;

convert.stdout.on('data', function(data) {

    graph.push(data);
    totalsize +=data.length;
}
convert.stdout.on('end', function(signal) {

    var image = Buffer.concat(graph, totalsize);
    // ... draw on pdf


}
```

Comment: A more efficient approach would be to just append chunks to an array inside the `'data'` handler and *then* call `Buffer.concat()` once in the `'end'` handler. If you want to be even *more* efficient, you can keep a running total of the chunk sizes that you can pass as a hint to `Buffer.concat()` instead of forcing `Buffer.concat()` to dynamically calculate the needed length.